# How to add new component parameters in Joomla on the fly?

Tags: joomla

usually its done by setting up the config.xml but what to do when my component needs more parameters at run-time ? There is little or zero information about, just 1-2 tutorials about custom parameters which could be used to archive the same thing but only if you're willing to write lots of bloat code for a very simple thing.

In my case my component is rather a little platform in it self, ie: users can add plugins from us. Of course I'd like to expose some options for such plugins in the component's options.

Is there any shortcut because if you look at the built-in component's code, you really don't want to do the same for each plugin...

well, thanks! any thoughts are welcome!

ps: may be there is something more compact like the Redux-Framework for Wordpress. I'd love to know there is library which can server both CMS systems.

**update**
'component' = Joomla component and by 'plugin' I mean my and non-Joomla plugin, hosted in a Joomla component. Imagine your Joomla component is just a host for external plugins.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add them with code? Or you want the plugins to add parameters?  When you say plugin do you mean like a Joomla plugin or just something that extends your component?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion; I updated the post. Yes, its about pushing options from external and non-Joomla plugins into the surrounding Joomla component. So yes, its extending my component only :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom field type, where you'll be able to implement all the logic that's needed.

In case you need to store the values with the component, add a hidden input field, and use javascript to populate the markup on load, and insert the values you want to store on user interaction (you can also store an object encoded in json).  Joomla will take care of saving and retrieving it.

[the docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type)

Comment: I'll take it! Do think I will be able to wrap this in something like MyComponentHelper->registerFieldset(..) ? Because this what's actually missing on this platform... btw. did you know that your avatar alongside your sirname has in germany a very certain taste ?...

Comment: If you mean your custom field could call a function in the helper to persist its values, definitely yes. Of course you'll have to write the function :-) .  Do you mean my avatar communicates wrath or anger?

Comment: i'm not sure, all I want is to call ::registerFieldSet(..) at the time when the back-end view is opening, so that the user can press the option button and can alter the new options added. may I didn't got the things right yet in Joomla and I am hoping I can make shortcut... the avatar is just great, but having this sirname in top does a quite 'gloomy' impression :-)